# What's the equivalent to IntPtr (C#) in Java?

Tags: c#, java, jna

What's the equivalent to IntPtr (C#) in Java (JNA)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference`

Answer (score 3):

I expect that would be a `com.sun.jna.ptr.ByReference` or one of its concrete sub-types.