# Java equivalent of IntPtr.ZERO?

Tags: java, intptr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the equivalent to IntPtr (C#) in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448814/whats-the-equivalent-to-intptr-c-in-java)

Is there a Java equivalent of C#'s *IntPtr.ZERO*? If there is not, is there any way to achieve the same behavior when passed to a JNA library interface call?

I am using this snippet to represent *IntPtr.ZERO*:

`private static final IntByReference ZERO = new IntByReference(0);`

Will I achieve the same behavior when passed into this *Kernel32* JNA interface?:

```
boolean CreateProcess(String lpApplicationName, String commandLine,
        int processAttributes, int threadAttributes,
        boolean inheritHandles, int creationFlags,
        IntByReference environment, String currentDirectory,
        STARTUPINFO startupInfo, PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation);
```

As so:
`CreateProcess(target, null, 0, 0, false, 4, ZERO, null, sInfo, pInfo)`

Comment: Sorry, looks like that refers to IntPtr and not IntPtr.Zero specifically.

Comment: I am not looking for the equivalent of _IntPtr_, I need the equivalent of _IntPtr.ZERO_.

Comment: I believe `null` is usually used equivalently in JNA.

Comment: @msandiford I believe your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a C# programmer, but if I understand IntPtr.ZERO correctly, then there is no Java equivalent. Java references can either be null, or assigned, there is no third case like this.

If you show us what you are trying to accomplish, where you think you need this, we could probably point you in the right direction (no pun intended).

---

Edit: response to comment from @Jire:

There may very well be a way to do what you want directly, but it seems like a tough road, trying map NtDll and Kernel32 interfaces directly into Java via JNA. As you have discovered, they're two quite different worlds, and there are lots of things that don't translate directly.

I'd suggest writing your own DLL that accepts command-style requests from the java application using simpler types that work well with JNA, and in turn invokes the appropriate  native window calls.

See [JNA - Mapping Types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access#Mapping_types) for a list of the data types that JNA can map between native code and Java.

If you decide that you must do this with no intervening dll, I wish you luck, and if you have success, please post the code for others to see.

Comment: I am trying to write Java software that does native Windows calls to run a program from a byte array (without ever having the real program hit the hard drive)

This is what I want to convert: http://pastebin.com/7Maq937s
Here is my Kernel32 interface (and this also defines the structures): http://pastebin.com/8acqJY8R
Here is my NtDll interface: http://pastebin.com/Q2CgHD37

The problem I'm having is with converting the functions of the C# class, which, I have written most here: http://pastebin.com/8fUybMc1

What I don't understand has been written in comments. My problems are mostly repeated.